# Partial Fractions Integration Question

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, partial-fractions

$$\int\frac{x^5+x-1}{x^3 +1} dx$$

Have tried everything ... polynomial long division, partial fractions, trig substitution etc...

Not for an assignment, so if a complete solution could be provided that'd be much appreaciated

Answer (score 6):

Hint:

$$\frac{x^5+x-1}{x^3 +1} = \frac{(x^3+x^2-1)(x^2-x+1)}{(x+1)(x^2-x+1)}$$

Comment: Would the first step not be to use polynomial long division?

Comment: @Guest Do you want the first step to be polynomial division?

Comment: Well, generally partial fractions is utilised when degree of the numerator is less than the degree of the denominator

Comment: @Guest Sure, just like how you were taught to use long division to divide two numbers and find the remainder when the given some fraction like $\frac{1210}{55}$. How would you go about simplifying that fraction?

Comment: Using the division algorithm ....

Comment: @Guest You sure? What if you noticed that $1210=121\cdot 10=11^2\cdot 10=11^2\cdot 5\cdot 2$, and $55=5\cdot 11$?

Answer (score 6):

First divide the denominator into the numerator to get

$$\frac{x^5+x-1}{x^3+1}=x^2 -\frac{x^2-x+1}{x^3+1}$$

Now we factor the denominator, $$x^3+1=(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$$

Note that we have cancellation so we get
$$\int x^2-\frac{1}{x+1} dx=\frac{x^3}{3}-\ln |x+1|+C$$

Comment: Thanks a lot ... can't believe I missed such a simple detail on cancelling out like terms

Comment: I didnt see it either, you just need to follow the method.